# What happens to registered users if I change the Active Directory App that my webapp uses for authentication?

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a webapp that authenticates users using [Active Directory OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) with a request like this (skipped some querystrings):

https://login.microsoftonline.com/**{tenant}**/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?

**response_type**=id_token+code

**client_id**={clientid}

**scope**=openid+offline_access+profile

If I'm not mistaken, that is the Implicit Grant Flow and it had been working fine until now that the login started returning a 302 with message:

> unsupported_response_type&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'response_type'+is+not+valid.+Expected+values+are+the+following:+'code'%2c+'token'%2c+'none'.+'id_token'+is+disabled+for+this+app

The solution to this is to edit the App Manifest in Active Directory inside the Azure Portal, but the thing is I don't have access to that App Registration and don't even know who the owner of the app is. I can't even find it searching in All Apps.

So I was thinking just registering a new app in the same AD and tenant and then just change my webapp to request the auth to the new clientID. My question is what happens to all the users that were already registered and does this solution affect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your uses will be effected in the sense that they will have to re-grant the permission for the app to act on their behalf.

If you have set the Enterprise application to only allow a preset of users you will need to make sure these users are set against the enterprise application - however this is not turned on by default and any user can authenticate against the application.